# Can't solve Run-time error 92: For loop not initialized. Any idea?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, onerror

I have a small loop to check all the worksheets and past and copy a column if certain criteria are met. However, after all worksheets are completed, I'm running into "Run-time error 92: For loop not initialized". I understand, `Next ws` will be addressed as long as the loop is running (until the very last worksheet) or if an error occurs. I don't get why `Next ws` is used after the loop is finished.
Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

```
Dim MonthBC As String
Dim YearBC As String
Dim Phase As String
Dim colBC As Long
Dim colNo As Long
Dim vCol As Variant
Dim coli As Long

MonthBC = Form_Start_Update.ComboBox_Month.Value
YearBC = Form_Start_Update.ComboBox_Year.Value
Phase = "Plan"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Debug.Print ws.Range("A1").Parent.Name
        colNo = ws.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        vCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range(Cells(8, 1).Address, Cells(10, colNo).Address).Value2)
        If colNo = 1 Then
        GoTo Continue_Next
        Else
            For coli = LBound(vCol, 1) To UBound(vCol, 1)
                On Error GoTo Continue_Next
                If IsDate(vCol(coli, 1)) = True Then
                    vCol(coli, 1) = Year(vCol(coli, 1))
                End If
                If vCol(coli, 1) = YearBC Then
                    If vCol(coli, 2) = MonthBC Then
                        If vCol(coli, 3) = Phase Then
                        colBC = coli
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC + 1).Address).EntireColumn.Insert
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC).Address, Cells(Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row, colBC).Address).Copy
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC + 1).Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        ws.Range(Cells(11, 10).Address, Cells(Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row, 10).Address).Copy
                        ws.Range(Cells(11, colBC).Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next coli
        End If
    End With

Continue_Next:
    Next ws
```

Comment: Just pointing two things: if you're addressing `ws` everywhere you need it, you don't need to use `With... End` and you could delete the line `GoTo Continue_Next` inside the first `If`.

Comment: Thanks @Pspl. Yes, the code is running without the `With` as you suggested. However, the Run Time Error still occurs. Any other ideas?

Comment: What error do you expect after line:                 On Error GoTo Continue_Next    ?

Comment: @ReneHanschke, I copied the code to my machine (without the edition lines) and didn't get any error. If you're careful enough you can use labels inside a `For... Next` statement. However you should avoid that (like suggested by @Daniel). I can't pinpoint any `Runtime Error` on the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using labels inside the loop. Change the logic of your code and get rid of them. FYI you need to reset error handling procedure when you goto label on error, but again, you want to get rid of labels anyway.

/e: to be more precise, `on error goto Continue_Next` goes to the label that's outside of the loop and I believe this is causing an error. If you're expecting error here, place `On Error Resume Next` on top, test your error then `If Err.Number > 0 then Exit For` - don't need the label. Remember to clear error and error handling procedure. Try something like this:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Debug.Print ws.Range("A1").Parent.Name
    colNo = ws.Cells(8, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    vCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range(Cells(8, 1).Address, Cells(10, colNo).Address).Value2)

    If colNo > 1 Then
        For coli = LBound(vCol, 1) To UBound(vCol, 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            'test your error
            If Err.number > 0 Then Exit For
            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsDate(vCol(coli, 1)) = True Then vCol(coli, 1) = Year(vCol(coli, 1))
            If vCol(coli, 1) = YearBC Then
                If vCol(coli, 2) = MonthBC Then
                    If vCol(coli, 3) = Phase Then
                        colBC = coli
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC + 1).Address).EntireColumn.Insert
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC).Address, Cells(Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row, colBC).Address).Copy
                        ws.Range(Cells(1, colBC + 1).Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        ws.Range(Cells(11, 10).Address, Cells(Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row, 10).Address).Copy
                        ws.Range(Cells(11, colBC).Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next coli
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Daniel! The code works as expected now. And - also thanks for your explanation! - I now understand the logic and error handling much better. What an enlightment ;-)

Comment: No worries, it's very important to understand how error handling works, there's a bit more to it! :) For example, expected error enables error handling procedure, which must handle error before another one occurs. Therefore it's important to handle and reset expected errors in strategic places. Anyway, I suggest you read more about it on google and familiarise with err.clear, on error goto -1 and 0, resume etc